# Attachments moved away from Item after validation and before submit process in Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.1

I have multiple File Browser Item fields on one page of Application in Oracle Apex.
What happens: When I miss any Item for which validation error fires, I want to hold that file to the browser but I usually loose it if I get that validation error. Is there a solution for the same like other Items fields hold previous value except File Browser Item field. Please see below ss:

[image]

Comment: Why are you listing three different APEX versions?

Comment: Have you enabled the 'Required' attribute for those items? I just ran a test and it does use client-side validation (doesn't submit the page) to say that the items are required. I'm not sure when that became a "feature"...

Comment: Thanks for replying . I am using validation not value required

Comment: Right, but did you got into the item and enable the Required setting? Do that and test again?

Comment: I did, changed the value required to yes but still I lost the file. Strange, I have other Item field also those data are not going away but issue relies with File Browser Item field only. Please let me know if I can provide you much info, any help will be appreciated much

Comment: Yeah, File Browse items a kinda like Password fields in that regard. What version of APEX are you using? If you open your browser's developer tools and run this line of code in the console, what do you see? `typeof apex.message.showErrors`

Comment: Apex version is 4.2

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty old version of APEX. That explains why you're not getting the client-side benefit of the Required attribute. As I don't have access to a 4.2 instance of APEX, I can't help you craft a specific solution for that version, but the basic idea would be to change the submit button so that it executes a little JavaScript before the page is submitted. If any required fields are null, you'd just show an error message instead of submitting the page. If you look at the Submit button (either create or save), do you see an Action setting? If so, what are the values?

Comment: I can't see Action option in button... I'll find a way through JS or DA because upgrade version can not be done as of now...

Comment: This guide to creating a Dynamic Action indicates the Action setting on buttons existed in 4.2 (you must have overlooked it): https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/schema/42/dynactions/dynactions.html#section7 Step 7 in the last section, Creating a Dynamic Action on a Button, mentions that "the button's Action property is automatically changed to "Defined by Dynamic Action." That's actually the value I was going to tell you to select. Have another look and let me know when you find it.

Comment: About this I am aware of ,  but adding DA for value required items is not feasible. There should be an another way to hold the file on browser, I am not satisfied to add so many DA manually on each Item fields.

Comment: You told me "I can't see Action option in button". Anyway, you don't need to create a Dynamic Action per item, you can use one Dynamic Action with the Execute JavaScript action to validate all of them in one shot. Let me know if you want any more help with this issue.

Comment: Much appreciated. Yes, It would be great help if you can help me with on JS code (just an example) I am not familiar with JS. Also, There are hidden fields too on the page so I have to make a mark that JS validation should ignore hidden items but I will manage these

Comment: The actual validation is quite simple: `$x('P68_FILE_1').value === ''` If that returns true, then the user didn't select a file. The question becomes: what should you do? Generally, when you submit the page and the validation fails, you display the error message at the top and optionally give some kind of indication at the item level as well. Since you don't have the APIs to do this easily, you'll have to do it the hard way by reconstructing the HTML normally used with JavaScript. I'll provide a very generic answer that will require you to do some work to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Anshul, 
APEX 4.2 is very old and no longer supported. A later (or preferably latest) version of APEX will behave differently as Dan explained above.

Can you import your application into apex.oracle.com (which is running APEX 20.1) and you will probably see better results. Based on this you can hopefully use it as justification to upgrade your environment.

Regards,
David

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I understand it is very old version but have to fulfill requirement, upgrading version of Apex is not handling as project as of now by the company.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your page-level attributes and a function like the following in the **Function and Global Variable Declaration**:

```
function validateItems(request) {
  var $file1 = $('#P68_FILE_1');
  var $file2 = $('#P68_FILE_2');
  var errorsFound = false;

  if ($file1.val() === '') {
    errorsFound = true;
    // Show item in error state
  }

  if ($file2.val() === '') {
    errorsFound = true;
    // Show item in error state
  }

  if (!errorsFound) {
    // I think doSubmit was the name of the function back then. If not, try apex.submit
    doSubmit(request);
  } else {
    // Show error message at top of page, I'll use a generic alert for now
    alert('You must select a file for each file selector.');
  }
}
```

Then, right-click the **Create** button and select **Create a Dynamic Action**. Set the name of the Dynamic Action to **Create button clicked**.

For the Action, set **Type** to **Execute JavaScript Code**. Enter the following JS in code:

```
validateItems('CREATE');
```

Finally, ensure that **Fire on Initialization** is disabled.

Repeat the process for the **Save** button, but change the request value passed to `validateItems` to **SAVE**.